# Send 2D String Array over Socket Connection In Java

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, multidimensional-array

I am building an android app in android studio and it is connected to my server via socket connection in LAN.

Here is part of my code as I am trying to send 2D string array to my clientside:

I need help in sending this 2D String Array at the server side and also,
receiving it in client side.

As shown below, I wanted to send 2D string array ---> String[][] tableconfig

Server side coding: ( Some part of it)

```
ResultSet columnrs=columnst.executeQuery(getColumn);
int numberOfColumns=columnmd.getColumnCount();;
String[][] tableconfig= new String[numberOfColumns-2][];
List<String> storedata=new ArrayList<String>();
ResultSet rsrs=columnst.executeQuery(queryL.toString());

    while (rsrs.next()){

             storedata.add(rsrs.getString(namaColumn[loop]));
    System.out.println(rsrs.getString(namaColumn[loop]));

         }

         tableconfig[loop]=new String[storedata.size()];
         tableconfig[loop]=storedata.toArray(tableconfig[loop]);

       queryL.delete(0, queryL.length() );
   }

}
```

Comment: This forum is really for help with specific problems, not for asking for code.

Comment: you need to iterate through the content of the array and send its content to a socket connection, both thing you would find a tons of solution in SO or google

Comment: i need to keep it in array form, for the ease of android client side. Besides, the tableconfig[][] is dynamically changes with the content of database as data in database can be updated from time to time.